# How to Mute Microphone of the Media Stream in Webrtc?

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I have tried the `stream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false`, But it does not work, Moreover, The `getAudioTracks()` is not currently supported in firefox..

Moreover `stream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = false` only works in chrome, But not in firefox.
I need a solution which is compatable with both.

Comment: I just tested in Firefox 30 and I was able to disable audio without issues.

Answer (score 7):

you should set `enabled` attribute

```
stream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false/true
```